# Google Places API returning incorrect \ incomplete places

Tags: python, pandas, google-api

I'm setting up a simple google places API python request code. 
It should return all places that match a text query. It is however returning other locations and not the ones I am looking for.

It mostly works for locations such as Schools, Libraries, Churches, Places of worship. However, at least one of my search terms doesn't return the expected results, instead it returns pretty much everything else.

```py
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm

global points
points = pd.DataFrame()
search = pd.read_csv("Search Terms.csv")
global page
global Type
page = 1
APIKEY = "MY API KEY"

def findPlaces(loc=("-33.8901","150.7191000"),radius=35000, pagetoken = None):
   global points
   global page
   global Type
   global Term
   lat, lng = loc
   type = Term
   url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location={lat},{lng}&radius={radius}&type={type}&key={APIKEY}{pagetoken}".format(lat = lat, lng = lng, radius = radius, type = type,APIKEY = APIKEY, pagetoken = "&pagetoken="+pagetoken if pagetoken else "")
   response = requests.get(url)
   res = json.loads(response.text)
   print(Type, "page: ", page)
   for result in res["results"]:


      temp = {
          "Name" : result["name"],
          "Lat" : result["geometry"]["location"]["lat"],
          "Lon" : result["geometry"]["location"]["lng"],
          "Type" : Type,
          "Search Term" : Term
          }
      points = points.append(temp, ignore_index= True)
   pagetoken = res.get("next_page_token",None)

   page += 1
   return pagetoken

pagetoken = None


for index, row in search.iterrows():
    termraw = row['Terms']
    Type = row['Type']
    terms = termraw.split(',')
    i = 0
    while i < len(terms):
        Term = terms[i]
        pagetoken = findPlaces(pagetoken=pagetoken)
        import time
        time.sleep(5)

        if not pagetoken:
            i += 1

print("cleaning")
points = points.drop_duplicates(subset ="Name", keep = 'first') 

points.to_csv('outputaged.csv')
```

As far as my understanding goes, if I feed in for example, "nursing homes" I should have a return that resembles   https://www.google.com/maps/search/Nursing+home/@-33.8132784,150.9377676,12z

However, the actual result seems to be everything excluding these things.

I've never really done any google API requesting so any help would be very useful.
Thanks,

A snippit of the output is attached.

```
0   -33.8688197 151.2092955 Sydney
1   -33.9166741 150.8525853 Bunnings Hoxton Park
2   -33.8641885 150.6407872 BP
3   -33.7961736 150.7070948 Penrith Anglican College
4   -33.8747193 150.7150313 Workers Hubertus Country Club
5   -33.7849683 150.6752473 Caroline Chisholm College
6   -33.7877012 150.7714889 Blue Cattle Dog Hotel
7   -33.7843743 150.7087178 Penrith Christian School
8   -33.789197  150.668553  SubwayÂ® Restaurant
9   -33.925649  150.854178  Goodstart Early Learning Hoxton Park
11  -33.7889187 150.6689905 Asian Pearl Chinese Restaurant
12  -33.8367893 150.7617273 Twin Creeks Golf & Country Club
15  -33.9090231 150.7862319 Czecho Slovakian Country Club
16  -33.8956637 150.8520624 Cecil Hills High School
17  -33.803243  150.804976  Liquorland Erskine Park
18  -33.7942519 150.788228  Red Rooster
19  -34.065         150.814167  Campbelltown
20  -33.9372737 150.845665  Carnes Hill Marketplace
21  -33.7888697 150.6684124 Glenmore Park Realty
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who runs into this issue in the future here's the issue:
I was giving the API a 'type' key rather than a 'keyword' key. This isn't very well documented.

Types have to be in [this](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types) list. Or else it will return everything in that location